# Tkinter message box crash: Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a hard-to-replicate crash when using `tkinter.messagebox` on a MacOS Monterey 12.2.1, python 3.8.13.

The system crashes about 50% of the time when I call `messagebox.showinfo(...)` or any of the functions under `messagebox`, with `Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)`

Code where it crashes:

```
print("Interpreter gets here")
messagebox.showinfo(message="No detections to export.  Select one with a completed scan to export", title='aa')
print("But never gets here - it crashes with Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)")
```

Known facts:

- I've tried replicating this in isolation, but can't get it to crash outside the context of my program.
- It crashes about half the time.
- The `messagebox.showinfo(...)` gets called from a Thread which is launched by the click of a button in the UI (I've also tried replicating this situation in an isolated test, but get no crash).

Anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you should only interact with the UI from the main thread.  i.e. - if you open up `messagebox.showinfo` or do any UI actions on any thread other than the main one, you should expect crashes.